# Run long SQL script for each database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a long SQL script i'd like to run for each of my databases on one server. What's the best way to do that?

I found this in my research:

```
EXEC    sp_msforeachdb  "
IF      '?'     IN ('lib1','lib2','lib3')   

BEGIN
        use ?;
        exec 'my_sp_long_sql_script'
END
"
```

I tried it but it needed me to create the sp in each library, which kind of defeats the purpose of the loop. Or how do I automate creating a sp for each library?

All I want to do is run my long_sql_script for each of my databases.

Comment: Are you running a script (a .sql file) or executing a stored procedure? Similar questions have been asked [many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+script+multiple+databases); personally I would write a small external batch file or script to do this ([SQLCMD scripting variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714(v=sql.100).aspx) can be useful). And if it's a deployment issue then you may prefer to build something into your build/deploy process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fully qualified name of the stored procedure instead of its relative name, to retrieve it from whereever it is defined. This is how SQL Server itself works.